# how to call method in parent component after ngOnInit of child component

Tags: angular

In the parent component, i want to wait the ngOnInit of child component.
I tried with setTimeout it's worked but i don't like to use it.

````
setTimeout(() => {
}, 1500); ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know your purpose but you can do it with an Output() and EventEmitter.
(This code hasn't been tested)

Parent

```
childInit() {
  console.log('Child is initialized');
}
```

```html
<child (initializedEmitter)="childInit()"></child>
```

Child

```
@Output() initializedEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();


ngAfterViewInit() { // Maybe you can try with ngOnInit()
  this.initializedEmitter.emit();
}
```